# SPARQL BIND inside UNION is too slow

Tags: sparql, wikidata

Given an IMDb ID, i want to get a list of directors and actors for that movie from Wikidata.

The problem is, I want to UNION both the director and actor query into a single column while also providing a new column with the role of director or actor.

Pretty easy query overall: first I get the movie entity from the IMDb ID, then I get all the directors from that movie followed by getting all the actors from that movie and UNION them together while filling a new column (`?role`) with the role.

This is what I have:

```
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?role ?imdb WHERE
{
  ?movie wdt:P345 "tt0110912" .
  { ?movie p:P57 ?cast .
    ?cast ps:P57 ?person .
    BIND("director" as ?role) .
  } UNION {
    ?movie p:P161 ?cast .
    ?cast ps:P161 ?person .
    BIND("actor" as ?role) . }
  
  ?person wdt:P345 ?imdb .
  OPTIONAL { ?cast prov:wasDerivedFrom ?ref . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?role ?imdb
ORDER BY DESC(?role)
LIMIT 100
```

This works and gives the result I want, problem is it takes about 10secs. If I remove the BINDs its instant speed, but I don't get a column with the roles.

Comment: You could also add `hint:Query hint:optimizer "None" .` somewhere in your query. Add `&explain` to your query URL to view execution plan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write this using **values** instead of **bind** and **union**.   The idea is that you're saying when the properties are one thing, then ?role is one thing, and when the properties are another, ?role is another. The easy way to do that with **values** is something like:

```sql
select ?owner ?pet ?petType {
  values (?hasPet ?petType) { 
    (:hasCat "cat")
    (:hasDog "dog")
  }
  ?owner ?hasPet ?pet
}
```

In your case, this would be:

```sql
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?role ?imdb WHERE
{
  ?movie wdt:P345 "tt0110912" .

  values (?p ?ps ?role) {
    (p:P161 ps:P161 "actor")
    (p:P57 ps:P57 "director")
  }
  ?movie ?p ?cast .
  ?cast ?ps ?person .

  ?person wdt:P345 ?imdb .
  OPTIONAL { ?cast prov:wasDerivedFrom ?ref . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?role ?imdb
ORDER BY DESC(?role)
LIMIT 100
```

When I run this at query.wikidata.org, it produces [35 results](https://query.wikidata.org/#PREFIX%20p%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20ps%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fstatement%2F%3E%0APREFIX%20wdt%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.wikidata.org%2Fprop%2Fdirect%2F%3E%0ASELECT%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3Frole%20%3Fimdb%20WHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20%3Fmovie%20wdt%3AP345%20%22tt0110912%22%20.%0A%20%20%0A%20%20values%20%28%3Fp%20%3Fps%20%3Frole%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%28p%3AP161%20ps%3AP161%20%22actor%22%29%0A%20%20%20%20%28p%3AP57%20ps%3AP57%20%22director%22%29%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%3Fmovie%20%3Fp%20%3Fcast%20.%0A%20%20%3Fcast%20%3Fps%20%3Fperson%20.%0A%0A%20%20%3Fperson%20wdt%3AP345%20%3Fimdb%20.%0A%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fcast%20prov%3AwasDerivedFrom%20%3Fref%20.%20%7D%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22en%22.%20%7D%0A%7D%0AGROUP%20BY%20%3Fperson%20%3FpersonLabel%20%3Frole%20%3Fimdb%0AORDER%20BY%20DESC%28%3Frole%29%0ALIMIT%20100) almost instantly.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that `BIND` leads to some problems with the query optimizer. You can try as an alternative to bind the role outside of the `UNION` clause, i.e.

```sql
PREFIX p: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/>
PREFIX ps: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/statement/>
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/>
SELECT ?person ?personLabel ?role ?imdb WHERE
{
  ?movie wdt:P345 "tt0110912" .
  ?person wdt:P345 ?imdb .
  { 
     ?movie p:P57 ?c1 . ?c1 ps:P57 ?person .
     ?movie p:P57 ?cast .
  } UNION {
     ?movie p:P161 ?c2 . ?c2 ps:P161 ?person .
     ?movie p:P161 ?cast . 
  }
  BIND(IF(bound(?c1), "director", "actor") as ?role)

  OPTIONAL { ?cast prov:wasDerivedFrom ?ref . }
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "en". }
}
GROUP BY ?person ?personLabel ?role ?imdb
ORDER BY DESC(?role)
LIMIT 100
```

(If you do not the `?ref` variable, you can omit the triple patterns to retrieve the `?cast` in the `UNION` clauses.)

Comment: You don't even need the union here.  Just use `values (?p ?role) { (p:P57 "director") (p:P161 "actor")}`, etc.

Comment: Right, is much more elegant. If I really understand, you meant to replace the whole UNION part by ` values (?p ?role) { (p:P57 "director") (p:P161 "actor")}
  ?movie ?p ?cast .`, right? Unfortunately, this leads to a timeout (at least at the time of writing). I guess it's similar to the performance issue with BIND. I don't know how Blazegraph is optimized more it, at a first glance this looks like a simple query.

Comment: AKSW, I was mistaken in what I wrote. OP uses two properties in each of the union sides (e.g., p:P171 and ps:P161).  It should be `values (?p ?ps ?role) ...`.  I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43392591/1281433). The results are almost instant.